# Textbox focus on button when hit enter?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

This is a textbox field I have and when a user enters in a value and hit enter, I want the value to submit when the user hit enter.

```
<div id="divUserInfo" >
    <table align="center">
        <tr  id="trDomain" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td class="tdLabel tdLabelInfo" >Domain Name</td>
            <td class="tdData">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDomain" runat="server" ToolTip="Network domain user is associated."></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRqdDom" runat="server" Text="required" CssClass="noshow" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Yes I know I'm formatting in a table and will not being using tables for my future projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Postback on TextBox loosing focus**

If you just want to do a postback when `TextBox` looses focus (by pressing `Enter`, `Tab` or moving focus to another control), set `AutoPostBack` property of the `TextBox` to *true*.

After writing something in the `TextBox` and making it loose focus, you'll get a postback. I suppose, however, that this can be raised **not only** on pressing Enter.
More information on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx.

**Postback by simulating submit Button click on pressing Enter**

If you want a postback only on pressing enter, you can put add a `Button` on the page and put it with the `TextBox` in the same `Panel` control. Then you should set `DefaultButton` property for this `Panel`. This should invoke button click on pressing *Enter* when the `TextBox` (or any other control in the `Panel`) is focused.

So, your code can look like this (the code hasn't been tested):

```
...
<asp:Panel ID="grouppingPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmitDomain">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDomain" runat="server" ToolTip="Network domain user is associated." />
    <asp:Label ID="lblRqdDom" runat="server" Text="required" CssClass="noshow" ></asp:Label>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitDomain" runat="server" Text="GO" OnClick="btnSubmitDomain_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
...
```

You can find more information about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx.

If you have any issues applying any of those solutions or further questions, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need a custom client-side event to respond to the `Enter` keypress to programmatically submit the form, or you'll need an `input` of type `submit`.  Pressing `Enter` in a textbox to submit the form is the default behavior if there is a submit button on the form.  If you choose to implement a custom event handler, you'll need to attach it to each textbox that should submit the form when the `Enter` key is pressed.

NOTE:  If you have more than one `submit` button on the form, the default behavior is to invoke *the first button* as they appear in the DOM.  If you don't want to display your official `submit` button first, you can use some CSS to rearrange the display or you can put a hidden button at the top of the form to serve as the "default action."

Answer (score 1):

First, register this javascript in your page_load event:

```
    Public Shared Sub jsTrapEnter(ByRef p_Page As System.Web.UI.Page)

    Dim sScript As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    sScript.Append("<SCRIPT language=""javascript"">" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("function fnTrapKD(btn){" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append(" if (document.all){" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("   if (event.keyCode == 13)" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("   { " & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("     event.returnValue=false;" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("     event.cancel = true;" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("     btn.click();" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("   } " & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append(" } " & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("}" & vbCrLf)
    sScript.Append("</SCRIPT>" & vbCrLf)

    If Not p_Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("ForceDefaultToScript") Then
        p_Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(p_Page.GetType, "ForceDefaultToScript", sScript.ToString)
    End If

End Sub
```

Then this method adds an attribute to each editor control that you want to have a default button:

```
    Public Shared Sub DefaultButton(ByVal objTextControl As Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl, ByVal objDefaultButtonID As String)

    objTextControl.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", String.Format("fnTrapKD(document.all.{0})", objDefaultButtonID))

End Sub
```

Then in our page_load event register the default button with each editor:

```
            DefaultButton(txtStreetNm, btnSearch.ClientID)
        DefaultButton(txtSuffix, btnSearch.ClientID)
```